# Android: Problems with MediaPlayer Class, not play a song

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

What is the problem with this code, because the music is not played?
It is a song with mp3 file format, weights 4 megabits in res/raw.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          mediaPlayer.start();
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pauseButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          mediaPlayer.pause();
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// assign the instance to mediaPlayer object

mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it in `OnCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music);

    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ing Tejada is your issue fixed?